# Is there an explicit formula for the inverse of $\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}$?

Tags: inverse

I apologize if this is trivial but I am stuck.

Given the bijective function $f:(0,2\pi) \to (-2,2)$ with
$$
f(x)=\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}
$$
where $\cot$ is the cotangent, how can I find an inverse $g:(-2,2)\to (0,2\pi)$? Is there an explicit formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Use this fact that $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}=\sin^2(x/2)$$ and that if $x\in(0,2\pi), |\sin(x/2)|=\sin(x/2)$

Comment: Spot on, my friend!! $\Large +1$

Comment: @amWhy: I am good and I am manipulating elements in a semigroup to generalize it. So hard Amy! wish me luck.

Comment: Good luck! Is  this for a presentation? a paper?

Comment: @amWhy: I missed your kind comment here, so sorry for myself :..( Yes for a paper.